# how to provide search contact by birthdate in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How to customize global search so it allow to search contact by birthdate in salesforce.
I have read somewhere that text field needs to be created and update it through workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a text field and use Workflow to populate the text field (with every edit). Be sure to format your text in a format your users will use, here is example of workflow formula for population of text field:

```
TEXT(Month(Birthdate))+ 
"/"+ 
TEXT(Day(Birthdate))+ 
"/"+ 
TEXT(Year(Birthdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Created new text field that is update through new process with formula

```
TEXT(Month( Birthdate ))+ 
"/"+ 
TEXT(Day( Birthdate ))+ 
"/"+ 
TEXT(Year( Birthdate ))
```

mark this text field as external id (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm&language=en) so it can be searchable through side bar search instead of using advance search
(https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004299).

update existing contact record with Salesforce Data Loader.
- keep process active.
- import all contact data with id  only as csv file.
- update contact data with matching as Id.
- so it will modify all contact data and update new text birthdate field as process is active.